# Ubuntu VM on Virtualbox keeps aborting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have `Virtualbox` (v4.3.18) installed on my Mac X (10.10) and created a VM with `Ubuntu` on it (ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso). After the installation was completed, it asked to reboot, and when I checked the storage settings, the iso had been automatically removed. I went ahead and install software on the VM, but walked away and came back to find it had `aborted`. When I try to `run` the VM again, I see the following messages and I am unable to get back to Ubuntu: [image: launch messages]:

The only thing I have been able to do is add the iso back in the storage settings and re-install Ubuntu to be able to use it, but always temporarily since it keeps aborting. I don't want to "try it without installing" it, I want to be able to turn it off and on whenever I want and not have to reinstall every time. Does anyone know why the VM is aborting?

Comment: I have been using my Ubuntu VM for the past couple hours (since the post) and this time, since I am done, I clicked on the close button. When I did this, I got prompted, as I expected, to save the state of the machine. I went ahead and did this and went back to the vbox management screen, started up the VM and it looks fine. I've closed it again and will check its integrity tomorrow. It seems that you MUST save the state of the machine before you walk away, otherwise, it aborts the installation - stinky, yeah.

Comment: I was not able to figure out the issue, but yesterday after I re-installed Ubuntu, and before I walked away, when I closed the window, I was able to specify "Save machine state". I tried re-starting the VM right after this and it worked. I am happy to report that it is still working today. I am not sure why  it aborts, but to workaround this, make sure you save the state of the machine before walking away.

Answer (score 2):

Is the "Enable EFI" parameter checked? it is on the system/motheboard page of the VM.

I met a similar problem once and checking the box solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be because of the virtual box problem. it might because of the memory issue. If you have less swap and it gets full then there is high chance of vbox machine gets aborted.
To check that first check weather your swap memory is full or not using htop command. If htop is not installed (`sudo apt install htop` in ubuntu, check for other flavors)
Put `htop` command and see if the swap is getting full. If yes you can increase the swap memory by following command

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

And then you do `htop` and see the swap size. it should be 8gb and not full. now your vbox won't be aborting repeatedly.
It solved my vbox problem after lot of research

Comment: This helped me, but I just did `restart` the computer to free the memories. Thx!

Comment: This is inside the VM right?

Comment: No, It should be outside the vagrant, this is for your system

Answer (score 0):

This started happening to me with VBox 5.1.24 and Ubuntu 17.04 both of which have the latest patches as of July 22 2017. Ubuntu Desktop would attempt to start for 5-10 minutes. The purple splash screen transitioned back to a black text screen with a blinking cursor. The VM would become Aborted after 5-10 minutes. Doubling the amount of RAM for the VM (to 8 GB) resolved the issue.